# Azure MobileApp custom authentication, refresh token

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services, custom-authentication

I need my app to support custom authentication against our private database, and following the advices on Adrian Hall book here https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/ I got no problem authenticating my users. The problem comes when I need to refresh the access token. 
As I'm forced to stay with custom auth, I have the following questions:

1) Should I call MobileServicesClient.RefreshUserAsync(), and if so, what kind of endpoint should I implement on the server? Will it reissue another token every time, invalidating the old? When should be the refresh call be made?

2) I've read about using a never-expiring refresh token, but I can't really find a sample implementation, or instructions on how to implement it in a custom auth scenario, could someone point me to the right direction?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I call MobileServicesClient.RefreshUserAsync(), and if so, what kind of endpoint should I implement on the server? Will it reissue another token every time, invalidating the old? When should be the refresh call be made?

I have checked the method `RefreshUserAsync` from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll` which would send a get request against the `/.auth/refresh` endpoint for refreshing the access token with the provider for your logged in user. Since you are using custom authentication, you could not use this method for refreshing the `authenticationToken`.

> I've read about using a never-expiring refresh token, but I can't really find a sample implementation, or instructions on how to implement it in a custom auth scenario, could someone point me to the right direction?

When using the `CreateToken` method from [AppServiceLoginHandler](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login/AppServiceLoginHandler.cs), you could specify the `lifetime` as `null`, then you would retrieve a never-expiring `authenticationToken` as follows:

```
JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(claims, signingKey, audience, issuer,null);
```

Additionally, you could try to build your endpoint for creating new token based on the old valid token as follows:

```
[Route(".auth/login/customRefreshToken")]
public IHttpActionResult RefreshToken([FromBody] RefreshTokenInput body)
{
    string tokenString = body.AuthenticationToken;
    try
    {
        var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenString);
        JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(jwtSecurityToken.Claims, signingKey, audience, issuer, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
        return Ok(new LoginResult()
        {
            AuthenticationToken = token.RawData
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest("$Error = {e.Message}, StackTrace = {e.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

**Note:** For your mobile client, you could use `MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync` for retrieving the new token, then parse the `authenticationToken` and update it to `MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken`.

**RESULT**

[image]

[image]